# jQuery find(): reference the current set root

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I reference the root (of the current set) from the `find` function?
Given

```
<div id="someid">
  <div id="garbage" class="test"></div>
  <div id="one" class="test">
    <div id="two" class="test">
      <div id="three" class="test">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to run a tentative query of the form

```
$('#someid').find(':root > .test > .test')
```

and I would like to get only the div `#two`.

However as far as I understand `:root` references the DOM root, not the current set (which in our case is the element `#someid`). In particular
`$('#someid').find(':root > .test > .test')` results in `[]`.

On the other hand `$('#someid').$('.test > .test')` matches both `#two` and `#three`, which is not the desired behaviour.

I know I could query `$('#someid > .test > .test')` but the point is that `someid` is unknown, and I am already given the object `$('#someid')` and I have to use it in the query.

I am interested in "selecting by path" because there might be some garbage in the DOM with class `test` before the desired nested construction.

UPDATE. The comment by @BoltClock is actually the answer, but links to the docs would be appreciated - otherwise I cannot rely on this solution.

Comment: I could do `$('#someid').children('.test').children('.test')` but this is a bit ugly

Comment: `$("#someid").find("div.test:eq(1)").html()`

Comment: You can do this with `$('#someid').find('> .test > .test')`, but AFAIK this is not documented anywhere and I'm not sure how safe it is to use.

Comment: Why would this specific selector need documenting, or be unsafe? It is a simple CSS selector. @BoltClock

Comment: @Billy: Because it wasn't always a CSS selector - it originated in jQuery's .find(). AFAIK that syntax has never appeared in any specification prior to selectors-4, which was drafted long after jQuery was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eq()` attribute for return only the `div` that you want.

**Example 1**

```js
$("body").append( $("#someid").find(".test:eq(1)").attr("id") )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someid">
  <div id="one" class="test">
    <div id="two" class="test">
      <div id="three" class="test">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With `find(".test")` you check each element on your page with the className `"test"`.

With `eq(1)` you return only the second element. (0 being the first element)

**Example 2**

```js
$("body").append( $("#someid").find(".test").eq(1).attr("id") )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someid">
  <div id="one" class="test">
    <div id="two" class="test">
      <div id="three" class="test">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but there might be some garbage (see updated question) before the desired nested construction, so I cannot rely on eq(1)...

Answer (score 0):

Just use the direct child selector at the beginning of your selector:

```js
$("body").append( $("#someid").find("> .test > .test").attr("id") );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someid">
  <div id="one" class="test">
    <div id="two" class="test">
      <div id="three" class="test">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't see why you would need to see documentation on this, or consider it unreliable; It is a simple CSS selector.

Comment: FYI: The change I made [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/69952?draftId=58400) was to the syntax highlighting - I removed the unnecessary highlight, because it was misleading.